# The function call with the address of the overload set is rejected by both Clang and GCC

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/9o79MGqdf)

```cpp
struct A{
    static void fun(int){}
    void fun(double){}
    void show(){
        (&A::fun)(0);   //#1 ill-formed
        //A::fun(0);    //#2 OK
    }
};
int main() {
   A::fun(0);
}
```

`#2` is accepted by GCC and Clang while `#1` is rejected by both. It appears to me that they should have the same treatment. My reason is, as per [over.match.call#general-2]

> If the postfix-expression is the **address of an overload set, overload resolution is applied using that set as described above**. If the function selected by overload resolution is a non-static member function, the program is ill-formed.

For `&A::fun`, its overload set is defined in [over.over#2]

> If there is no target, all non-template functions named are selected.

That means the overload set consists of the static and non-static member function of class `A`. Obviously, the static member function is better than the non-static member function with the argument of type `int`.

Hence, it violates neither

> If the function selected by overload resolution is a non-static member function, the program is ill-formed.

nor

> Otherwise, a contrived object of type T becomes the implied object argument;112 if overload resolution selects a non-static member function, the call is ill-formed.

I wonder that, Are both GCC and Clang wrong on this example?

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer. But common sense... How is `&A::fun` supposed to be meaningful ? It could be any of two functions.

Comment: @Lala5th In your example,  `int (X::*p4)(long) = &X::f;` is governed by [over.over#4]. Since the target is a pointer to member function, hence only non-static member functions match that target. It is different with my example.

Comment: @Jeffrey `It could be any of two functions.` Exactly, hence the overload set contains these two functions. *If the postfix-expression is the address of an overload set, overload resolution is applied using that set as described above.* will apply to this overload set in order to select the best viable function.

Comment: There is no such thing as "address of an overload set".

Comment: Surprisingly, MSVC compiles #1 fine

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. "address of an overload set" is indeed a bit confusing wording. I guess it means an address that needs to be overloaded.

Comment: "address that needs to be overloaded" isn't something that has a basis in reality either. An address cannot be overloaded. You can overload a function.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I meant the function address that should be determined by an overload resolution. "address of overload set" is the utterance of the standard.

Comment: I was wrong, there is such a thing as address of an overload set.

Comment: [expr.unary.op]/6 contains a non-normative note that could be interpreted as stricter than the referred to sections above: "The address of an overloaded function can be taken only **in a context that uniquely determines which version of the overloaded function is referred to** (see [over.over]). Since the context might determine whether the operand is a static or non-static member function, the context can also affect whether the expression has type “pointer to function” or “pointer to member function”. ". Key here would be what "context" is (how narrow?).

Comment: @dfrib As I said in the question, [over.match.call#general-2] says it will use the **set** to do the further overload resolution as described above, and the note after this bullet implies somrthing.

Comment: @dfrib In other words, if the address has identified by taking address, it will not necessary to undergo the overload resolution, which does not conform with "using the set as described above"

Comment: Possibly relevant https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29143 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#704 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#162